# How to run UIAutomator on emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-uiautomator

I am able to run my UIAutomator test on a real device. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. `<sdk_dir>/sdk/tools/android create uitest-project -n <test_name> -t 1 -p <workspace_dir>/<test_name>`
2. `cd <workspace_dir>/<test_name>`
3. `ant build`
4. `<platform-tools/adb push`
5. `<workspace_dir>/<test_name>/bin/<test_name.jar> /data/local/tmp`
6. `<platform-tools/adb shell uiautomator runtest <test_name.jar> -c <package_name.classname>`

Does anyone know how to execute the test on an emulator? (I am using Mac - emulator64-arm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always run UIAutomator tests on Android device emulator

All that you need is to find out what devices are connected to your pc:

```
<platform-tools/adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5555 device
HTCDesireX device
```

once you have the device id of emulator, use `adb -s <emulator_id>` instead of `adb` , you new steps would be:

```
<platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5555 push <workspace_dir>/<test_name>/bin/<test_name.jar> /data/local/tmp
<platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5555 shell uiautomator runtest <test_name.jar> -c <package_name.classname>
```